# ERROR : Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy full compilation mode. [object Object]

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-module-federation

nx run app-name:build --verbose --with-deps

throws the following error,

**ERROR :**

Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy full compilation mode.
**[object Object]**

NX   Running target "app-name:build" failed

Failed tasks:

- lib-name:build

Hint: run the command with --verbose for more details.

---

The problem is I am unable to see the detailed error log.

The compiler just says **[object Object]** even i use --verbose.

How do I see the error logs or did anyone face this issue before ?